# Writing a method with a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, set

I'm new to Java and I have a modelling question.

I have a class called CarRentalCompany, which holds a set of Car objects. With each Car object, a set of Reservation objects is associated. In the Car class, I have a method called getAllReservations which returns all reservations for that car as a Set. Each Reservation object has a carRenter associated with it, stored as a String (just a name). Therefore I have a method getCarRenter in the Reservation class which returns a String.

Below you can find the code of a method which I wrote in the class CarRentalCompany which gives a set of Reservation objects by renter name.

```
public Set<Reservation> getReservationsBy(String renter) {
    Set<Reservation> res = new HashSet<Reservation>();
    for(Car c : cars) {
        for(Reservation r : c.getAllReservations()) {
            if(r.getCarRenter().equals(renter))
                res.add(r);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

My question now is: how can I write a method in the CarRentalCompany class which returns the name of the renter with the most reservations made for that rental company?

The method has to look like this:

```
public String getBestCustomer(){
     ??
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Streams to build a frequency map and return the one with the highest count:

```
public String getBestCustomer() {
    return cars.stream()
            .map(Car::getAllReservations)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Reservation::getCarRenter, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .orElse(null);
}
```